# How to set position of objects in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I have Labels and JButtons i want to define the position in JFrame.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GuiFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("This is a test");
        f.setSize(400, 150);
        JRadioButton ButtonServer = new JRadioButton("Server");
        JRadioButton ButtonClient = new JRadioButton("Client");

        InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        Label lip = new Label("Your IP is : " + thisIp.getHostAddress());
        Label setup = new Label("Setup as ");
        JButton ButtonOk = new JButton("OK");

        Container content = f.getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.white);
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(lip);
        content.add(setup);
        content.add(ButtonServer);
        content.add(ButtonClient);
        content.add(ButtonOk);
        // f.addWindowListener(new ExitListener());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

setLocation() doesnot seem to work here. How to manage the object's position in JFrame?

Comment: See [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use proper **LayoutManager**. E.g. `GridBagLayout`.

Or you can combine multiple nested panels assigning own *LayoutManager* for each panel.

The worst way is to set layout to null and use `setBounds()`

Comment: Agree, setLayout null is a bad way to do it!

Comment: I have seen some LayoutManager but none of the LayoutManager seem to have feature to set the location(x,y) in the JFrame. Is there any?

Answer (score 3):

`FlowLayout` gives you some options. Look [here](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/awt/FlowLayout/FlowLayout.CENTER.html) .

For Example

```
   FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
   layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.CENTER);
   c.setLayout(layout);
   c.add(panel);
```

Answer (score 2):

I always use this:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

:)

Answer (score 0):

The Netbeans GUI Builder is great.  I suggest you look into it.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html