# Object placement in Java Applets

Tags: java, applet

Edit: I am going to be using a GroupLayout I would still appreciate some helpful formatting advice. I'm relatively new to java, so it would be great to have some assistance from a large coding community.

Hi i'm in a java class currently, and we are required to do an applet of our own for our final. I'm not the best with placing objects (JButtons,textfields,checkboxes) in certain positions. I understand it goes like "`variable.setLocation(width,height)`" but after several tries I haven't gotten it to format correctly. In my applet I want to have 3 different entry sheets (sheet consisting of a text field for user-input, a JLabel, and two buttons), but when running the code everything is all meshed together. 
I would appreciate some helpful tips and tricks for organizing things in an (awt) applet.

Thank you 
(if needed I can add the code I have currently)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set position of objects in JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005484/how-to-set-position-of-objects-in-jframe)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [how to use Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You are asking a question on a very broad topic, but try to follow through some of the tutorials. The link I provided shows you some examples of the different layout managers with links explaining how to use them. At the very least, it could help you to ask a more specific question.

Comment: (first of all thank you so much) Would you happen to know when using a grouplayout (or any layout) are you creating the layout in the init class or in paint class?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used an applet, but I would try the init class.